# How can I still use functions in excel and print their output ( and not the function) to my python prog.?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

This is the code I'm using but, If I use a function in excel, python prints only the function and not it's output. I imagine this is normally fixed using an intermediary like notebook, but the Arabic typeface does not transfer over. Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated.
  Thanks,
   William M. Hollingsworth
rom openpyxl import load_workbook

def main():

```
wb = load_workbook(filename ="F:\\Quran Gematria.xlsx", read_only=True)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

bigdict = {}

rowcount = 0

for row in ws.rows:

    rowdict = {}

    rowdict['words'] = row[0].value
    rowdict['sum'] = row[1].value
    rowdict['prime']=row[2].value
    rowdict['form'] = row[3].value
    rowdict['verse'] = row[4].value

    bigdict[rowcount] = rowdict

    rowcount += 1

for wordkey in bigdict:

    if(bigdict[wordkey]['form'] ==74):

       print(bigdict[wordkey])
```

main()

Answer (score 0):

set `data_only` to `True` when load workbook:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('forecast.xlsx', data_only=True)
```